# How did Saki meet Shun near the end of the show?

Tags: from-the-new-world

About halfway through the series, I thought Shun had killed himself in order to prevent any further damage to others.

However, in the last few episodes, Saki hears his voice as he gives her some very important advice. In the second to last episode, she even seems to see Shun in front of her. However, he seems to disappear in an instant, and she sees Kiroumaru instead. She later hears his voice once more as he tells her the solution to get rid of Maria and Mamoru's child.

Were these just hallucinations, or was there some supernatural force going on?

Comment: I am pretty sure she is hallucinating because in the last episode there was a scroll (22:18) saying “the power of imagination changes everything”

Answer (score 5):

Yes, she's hallucinating. The evidence for it at the start of episode 24 is irrefutable.

[image] [image]

**Why would she be hallucinating?**

It safe to say that given what Saki has gone through, she isn't in the best state of mind. With all the death and destruction she's witnessed and experienced, she's probably in some form of denial.

**Where does the advice from Shun come from?**

Herself actually. Her own subconscious mind.

When you're in such a hypnotic effect, things from deep in the back of your mind can come forward at unusual times. This is the same reason why hypnosis is sometimes used to bring back memories for criminal investigations and why artists can do their greatest works under times of extreme stress.

Comment: It's still weird that he was giving her such helpful advice if he was just a hallucination... I wonder if the book has more info.

Comment: It's a psychological effect actually. When you're in such a hypnotic effect, things from deep in the back of your mind can come forward at unusual times. So really, all the knowledge that Saki obtains from Shun during these hallucinations is actually from herself - her subconscious self.

Comment: Images aren't working for me :(... Anyway, this is just a speculative answer so far (maybe that's what the images are for - what were they?).

Comment: @Omega Yeah, that's what the images were for. It's side-by-side comparison two seconds apart of what Saki is seeing. Are all imgur images down for you? Everything seems fine on my end.

Comment: They're now working. Yeah, it looks plausible that she's hallucinating. Although it still concerns me how the extensive interaction between Saki and Shun is. Maybe he's projecting into her mind, until someone interrupts them by standing in the middle.

Comment: Hearing advice, remembering what they said and seeing a dead loved one are all very common plot devices. You hardly even need to go to the extent of justifying it as plausible in real life... it happens in basically every second anime where a main character dies.